# Is there a "Merge Parts" tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, digitizing, tools, multipart

In the advanced digitizing toolbar, QGIS has these 3 tools: Split Features, Split Parts, and Merge Features. Is there a tool or equivalent algorithm for the logical fourth one: "Merge Parts"?

This would have the opposite effect of Split Parts, which takes one part of a multipart feature and splits it into two adjoining parts of the same feature. Conversely, "Merge Parts" would take two (or more) adjoining parts of the same feature and make them a single part of that feature. It would not affect the singlepart/multipart status of the feature (or the layer as a whole).

In the image below there are two multipolygon features, which I realize I should have called Feature A and Feature B (rather than Polygon A and Polygon B). Feature A has 2 parts, and Feature B has 4 parts; note that parts 1 and 2 in Feature B share a common boundary. I've selected Feature B, and I'd like to execute a tool to join parts 1 and 2 into a single part, as shown in the "after" section. Feature B would then still be a multipolygon, but would have only 3 parts instead of 4.
[image]

The closest I can find is the "merge lines" algorithm; however this would not work with multipolygon features. It also merges all connected parts of a line feature, instead of just selected ones. (Is it even possible to select individual parts?) Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I should add, there is an easy and fairly obvious workaround, which is to use the Multiparts to Singleparts tool (which makes a new, separate feature out of each part of a multipart feature) and then use Merge Features to re-combine the resulting features (with any adjoining ones being merged into a single part). My question is really whether there is any existing tool that does this by design.

Comment: Could you draw a sketch about what such merge parts operation would do to support your literal explanation?

Comment: Not sure why "merge selected features" does not do what you need? How about "Dissolve" tool? And just to be clear: you are not trying to merge parts of multipolygons to singlepartpolygons that do not share a boundary?

Comment: @MrXsquared: "Merge selected features" requires selecting at least 2 features, which then get merged into one feature. "Merge parts" would perform an operation on only a single feature. "Dissolve" likewise requires combining separate features, not parts of a single feature. And your clarification is correct, I am not trying to do that. I am merging parts of multipolygons, that share a boundary, into a single part of the same multipolygon.

Comment: @user30184, I'll see if I can come up with a sketch, but in the meantime, here's an easy way to picture what I'm asking:
1) Select a feature
2) With the Split Parts tool, draw a line through the selected feature
3) You now have separate, adjoining parts of the feature
4) Select "Undo"

I'm looking for a tool that does just steps 3-4, without needing steps 1-2.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but this sounds like you have invalid geometries. Try running `Fix geometries` from processing toolbar (select Polygon B Part 1 and Polygon B Part 2 for this) before executing `merge selected features`.

Comment: @MrXsquared, you're right to be unsure, as I don't have any problem with my geometries and I'm not trying to execute "Merge selected features". However, since you mention it, how would one go about selecting the separate parts of a feature (as this would be necessary in using the tool I'm asking about)?

Comment: @Nathan, Contiguous parts are considered a topological error and can be linked with the _Fix geometries_ tool. In my case (QGIS 3.4.3), _Split Parts_ produces always invalid geomeries and I just don't use it.

Comment: There should be no need for such a tool because as told, parts of multipolygon must not have shared boundaries or they are invalid by the Simple features specification. Have you already tried Fix geometries?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, I don't use Split Parts either; that was simply a means of illustrating the question; an easy way to create the condition of separate but adjoining parts. What usually necessitates it for me is non-adjoining parts that become adjoining through additional digitizing.

Comment: @user30184, I hadn't tried Fix Geometries since it hadn't yet been given as an answer. So I tried it just now; it did not merge the parts. Returning to the question, then, is there a tool that simply merges parts?

Comment: I don'rt believe so because if you read the comments above, there should not ever be a situation that you have with parts sharing a common border. That is a topology error. And if parts are apart as they should they cannot be merged. Could you add one such invalid multipolygon as WKT so people can try to fix it?

Comment: I had read the comments, but none had yet answered whether there was a tool; only whether such a tool "should" be needed. I think now that you're right, and there isn't a Merge Parts tool. However, it appears there is in fact a need for the tool, since as you say, adjoining parts are an error and should be corrected. "Fix geometries" doesn't do that.
Here's a WKT string for a feature generated by "Fix geometries"—note that it still contains adjoining parts: https://pastebin.com/1ibYDzR5

Comment: @Nathan back when I first suggested `Fix geometries` tool, I did not do this without testing it myself before. Now I just tried with your WKT polygon and could not make it work. Only thing I discovered were two doubled numpoints. But removing them did not make any difference. However, here is an invalid polygon I created for testing, just like yours, but it can be merged/fixed using fix geometries tool: https://pastebin.com/LNtgB5Tf Now I really dont know whats going on...

Comment: I was able to fix a geometry if the parts overlap, rather than just touch; however, that's not a situation that has come up in my actual work. What's apparent is that Fix geometries and/or Snapping are creating geometries that aren't as topologically precise as they should be—too few decimal places, perhaps?—and that the issue is beyond the scope of my question. What's relevant is that conditions do, in fact, exist where there is an unmet need to merge parts; thus, the absence of that need is not evidence for the answer to my question.

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is that there is a projection issue when digitizing. Whenever I use the same CRS for the layers and the project, the snapping is exact. And I can not find a way that two parts of a feature can not be joined with the _Fix geometries_ tool as long as they are adjacent (exactly adjacent).

Comment: Projection issues sound very plausible. Whatever the cause, I would suggest also testing it with the Merge Features tool; if that tool is able to compensate for these minute snapping errors, that would also show evidence that a Merge Parts tool is needed that can likewise compensate.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a tool or equivalent algorithm for the logical fourth one: "Merge Parts"?

No, there isn't.

The adjacent parts of a multipolygon are considered a topological error and must be linked with the *Fix geometries* tool.

> Is it even possible to select individual parts?

No, it isn't.

You can select features, not individual parts.

> Is there anything else I'm missing?

I don't know. But you can refer to parts of collections with the `geometry_n()` function in expressions.

For example, you can create a new feature (in a separate layer) with the *Geometry by expression* tool, that contains the combination of two parts (or more if the function is nested) of a feature or of several, of any layer. If the parts are adjacent, they will form a single part in the new feature.

To create a feature formed by parts 1 and 2, of the feature_ID 0, of the 'multipolygons' layer:

```
combine( 
    geometry_n( geometry( get_feature_by_id( 'multipolygons', 0)), 1), 
    geometry_n( geometry( get_feature_by_id( 'multipolygons', 0)), 2)
    )
```

Note than the *Geometry by expression* tool copies the table from the input layer. If the input layer have more than one features, more than one features will be created, but only one will have a valid geometry with that expression.

---

**UPDATE:**

About the WKT of the Multipolygon provided in the comments (https://pastebin.com/1ibYDzR5), I can't seem a line shared by both parts.

When loading the feature in QGIS, it can be seen (with an appropriate zoom level), that the parts are not adjacent.

Upper:
[image: upper]

Lower:
[image: lower]

Be sure to snapping when digitizing and editing ([here is the manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html)). Otherwise, you can not merge those parts as they are in any way.

Comment: That there is no Merge Parts tool does seem to be the correct answer, thanks! However, it does not seem to be correct that "Fix geometries" will merge parts. I'm unable to reproduce that.

Comment: @Nathan, If _Fix Geometries_ tool does not merge them, it is because they are not adjacent, or they are not parts of the same feature. If they are adjacent but are not parts of the same feature, but they are in the same layer, the _Dissolve_ tool should also merge them. If they are adjacent but are parts of different features of different layers, the `combine()` function should merge them. If nothing merge them, they are not adjacent.

Comment: @Nathan, check your original geometries. It's evident that they have a topological error. If you don't find the error in them, share them and we'll try to look for it together.

Comment: It's only evident that the fixed geometries have a topological error; the original ones were created with snapping enabled, as you suggest, so they should not. (If they do, it's the result of some further error that's beyond the scope of my question.) Since this data only exists for illustrative purposes, I'd have to re-create it if we wish to explore further.

Comment: Alternatively, a "split parts" tool that could be used by hand (e.g. click on feature that you want separated by parts) could help us while doing manual edits?  I'm struggling to find a tool like that, is there maybe a plugin that can do it?

Comment: You can select a feature and run Multipart to singleparts tool. I don't know a plugin to dump clicked part to a new feature. If you can't find a related question just ask it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the features are actually touching I think the best solution is still to use the split features tool followed by the merge selected features tool.
Not a one-click solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To join singleparts to multiparts, i use the tool "Collect geometries" that i found in the Processing toolbox

Answer (score 0):

For Polygons, Best way I found as a workaround is to use Multi-part to Single Part tool in toolbox..  that makes each part a separate feature..  then using outline symbology for the polygon, align/overlap the borders of the individual features you want to merge..  then use the Merge Features tool by selecting the polygons you want to merge and then Merge..

Before merge of individual parts converted to individual feature/single part..
[image]

After merge of individual feature/single parts
[image]